# A simple Query causing high CPU in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

We are noticing below SQL is causing very High CPU and its been executed 10,000 times. Is there a way we can tune this T-sql?

```
SELECT ISNULL(max(trans_seq),0) +1  
FROM inv_inventory_journal  
WHERE organization_id = @P0  
AND wkstn_id = '600'
```

From Execution Plan, it is suggesting to create the following index.

```
/*
Missing Index Details from ExecutionPlan1.sqlplan
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 98.8039%.
*/

/*
USE [LKY_Xcenter]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[inv_inventory_journal] ([organization_id],[wkstn_id])
INCLUDE ([trans_seq])
GO
*/
```

[image]

### Table Structure

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using an IDENTITY column? You'll find it has a lot less contention than this max()+1 solution. Also, this query is in a serializable transaction, right? On its own, you can get multiple sessions retrieving the same value under the default isolation level.

Comment: The suggestion seems correct. The parallelism might have occurred because of missing index forcing SQL Server to prepare this plan. Please create NCI as suggested and again run the query and look at actual execution plan. Also please add table structure and information about any index DDL

Comment: @Shanky so, you are suggesting to create the index?

Comment: What @AaronBertrand said. Also, please post your table definitions as create statements instead of screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Based on your schema it looks like `trans_seq` can't be null so I would remove the `isnull` from the `select` as that would have a small amount of CPU overhead in just checking the value that is returned from the `max` function.

```
SELECT max(trans_seq) +1  
FROM inv_inventory_journal  
WHERE organization_id = @P0  
AND wkstn_id = '600'
```

Also if your query is always setting the `wkstn_id` to a constant 600. You could create a filtered index on that column.

```
USE [LKY_Xcenter]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[inv_inventory_journal] ([organization_id],[wkstn_id])
INCLUDE ([trans_seq])
WHERE [trans_seq] = 600;
GO
```

The nice thing about filtered indexes is that from an IO standpoint they only contain the rows that satisfies the `where` statement defined in the index so you could get better performance from them.

One thing of *note* with the filtered indexes is that in order for the query optimizer to use them the value in the `where` clause must be a constant in the query.

Here is a couple of references to using filtered indexes:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/what-you-can-and-cant-do-with-filtered-indexes/)

Answer (score 0):

From what i experienced using indexes in big table.
It seems the sql engine will optimally used index in a set of columns.

For example, your primary key consist of set of columns. But the index of that set will not be used in sql optimation unless the whole set of column is used in the query.

That is why your original query did not use the index.

So, yes. To optimize the use big data table , index must be created for each specific set of columns used in query.

Sql server execution plan analysis help a lot to analize wich columns should be indexed.

See [SQL server design guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835095(v=sql.110).aspx)

This basic index design guide would also applied to other rdbms engine

Other way to optimize query that use computing or formula is by alter the table to include computed columns. 
Compute column can be added to index.